# Appending a self constructed class in priority que gives TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Node'

Tags: python, class, typeerror, priority-queue, huffman-code

```
import sys
from queue import PriorityQueue

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data = None):
        self.value = data
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

class Huffman():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    
    def encoding(self):
        my_dict = {}
        for i in self.data:
            my_dict[i] = my_dict.get(i, 0)+1
        q = PriorityQueue()
        for i, j in my_dict.items():
            q.put((j,i))
        while q.qsize() >= 2:
            val_1 = q.get()
            val_2 = q.get()
            new_node_1 = Node(val_1[0]+val_2[0])
            if isinstance(val_1[1], str):
                new_node_1.left = val_1[1]
            else:
                new_node_1.left = val_1[1]
            if isinstance(val_2[1], str):
                new_node_1.right = val_2[1]
            else:
                new_node_1.right = val_2[1]
            q.put((new_node_1.value, new_node_1))
```

Herein, I am getting an error in **while loop**, after a few operations it fails to use the method **q.get()**, or **q.put()**.
For example, `Huffman('AADCIDCVUSHDUSHUSAHDIADHIAD').encoding()`
I do not want to change entire code, but just want to change priorities such that it priorities entries on the basis of first element (which is integer) only.

Comment: You are adding a Node in a priority queue that accepts a string. That is the issue. I don't really know if you can fix it without changing a little your code.

Comment: @LucasBelfanti I can add a Node in a priority que that is not an issue. Issue arises when it tries to compare Node with string to decide priorities. Thus, it gives that comparison is not possible. Also, from the python's documentation we can find that comparison between two different class is not possible. My argument is that the container of priority que is allowing Node but the comparison operators are stopping it. For example, my priority que includes integer and string both rather just strings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the Priority Queue doesn't know how to compare a str with a Node. You have to override the comparator functions in your Node class to let the Priority Queue know how to compare two different types.

Example (change the comparators as you want):

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.value = data
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

    def __lt__(self, obj):
        """self < obj."""
        return self.value < obj

    def __le__(self, obj):
        """self <= obj."""
        return self.value <= obj

    def __eq__(self, obj):
        """self == obj."""
        return self.value == obj

    def __ne__(self, obj):
        """self != obj."""
        return self.value != obj

    def __gt__(self, obj):
        """self > obj."""
        return self.value > obj

    def __ge__(self, obj):
        """self >= obj."""
        return self.value >= obj
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a better solution. Something which skip this entire process.

Comment: Well, maybe you could avoid the override of some of them, for example the `__ne__`, the `__eq__`, the `__ge__` and `__le__`. I mean you have to override the ones that the Priority Queue uses, but I'm afraid it's the most pythonic solution.

Comment: I want to return True for each operator by just two line of code, or just use an universal comparison operator. Like `def __cmp__(self,other)` `return cmp((self.left), (other.left))`. Or, change priority list such that it does not go through inner comparison. I have upvoted your solution, because it was helpful but looking forward for others.